# error while executing dart code in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, dart-null-safety

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:io';

main(){
  print("Enter the first number:");
  String num1 = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  print("Enter the second number:");
  String mun2 = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  print(num1 + mun2);
}
```

Whenever i try this code to extract the input i get this error, console doesn't ask for input as well, set aside to printing string with input variable!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`dart:io` doesn't work on the web. Try to run it as a console application.

Comment: HOW ??? I AM NOT RUNNING ON WEB, AM I??

Comment: It is clearly there in the logs that is `debug service on chrome`.

Answer (score -1):

01 - Frist Check Your Internet

02 - After Check Your Emulator Showing The Bottom Right

(Frist Run Cmd - Flutter Doctor Command , i think Flutter Missing Operations.)

flutter doctor